# How Apache manages HTTP request when it is python which is going to response? it is thread based or process based?

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, process, wsgi

What i mean is when some one makes a http request, does it like apache spawn a **new process or thread**.
My configuration is `apache + python with wsgi module`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Requests will be handled by the already running single thread, or a thread from a preallocated thread pool. For more information about how it works with mod_wsgi read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html

Be aware that it is better to use daemon mode of mod_wsgi and disable Python inside the main Apache processes altogether. For details of that see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html